# Spring Security hiding single element of website

Tags: spring-security

Hi i am new to Spring and I have a following problem:

I had succesfully implemented login mechanism
on my website, but I know how to make it work only
on specified subpages by:

```
  <http entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint" auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
```

And I would like to hide only choosen elements on subpages that are 
visible for any user.

For example anyone can acces a subpage to read an article on my website, but
only registered user can add a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may want to use `<sec:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled"/>` in your web context, so that you can use that annotation `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('YOUR ROLE')")` in your controller.

Than you can user the spring-security tags to show/hide content on your jsp page depending on the connected user role.

you can have more docs here http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity.html

Comment: Thank you very much :) Documentation part that I needed http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/taglibs.html